# ActiveMQ Artemis address security roles application order

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have some unclear moments with security for addresses. The application order of security roles is not clear for me.

Let's imagine, we add security settings for `test_user` (via `addSecuritySettings`) {send, consume, browse, ...} to `ADR.TEST.#`. From [wildcard docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html) this settings will apply to `ADR.TEST.IN`. And it's true, if I check via Hawtio `getRolesAsJson()`.

Then I give with same actions same security settings for `another_user` to `ADR.TEST.IN`. In result i have 2 users (test_user, another_user) with same permissions for `ADR.TEST.IN`.

If then I make same step for third user `last_user` to `ADR.TEST.#`, `last_user` would not have any permissions for `ADR.TEST.IN`, what suits `ADR.TEST.#`.

Is it bug or feature?

UPD: Code example:

```
ActiveMQServerControl activeMQServerControl;
...
activeMQServerControl.addSecuritySettings("ADR.TEST.#", "test_user", "test_user", "test_user", "test_user", "test_user", "test_user", "test_user");
activeMQServerControl.addSecuritySettings("ADR.TEST.IN", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user");
activeMQServerControl.addSecuritySettings("ADR.TEST.#", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user", "test_user,last_user");
```

This is output  for `activeMQServerControl.getRolesAsJSON("ADR.TEST.IN")` after first assignment:

> [{"name":"test_user","send":true,"consume":true,"createDurableQueue":true,"deleteDurableQueue":true,"createNonDurableQueue":true,"deleteNonDurableQueue":true,"manage":true,"browse":false,"createAddress":false,"deleteAddress":false}]

After second:

> [{"name":"test_user","send":true,"consume":true,"createDurableQueue":true,"deleteDurableQueue":true,"createNonDurableQueue":true,"deleteNonDurableQueue":true,"manage":true,"browse":false,"createAddress":false,"deleteAddress":false},{"name":"another_user","send":true,"consume":true,"createDurableQueue":true,"deleteDurableQueue":true,"createNonDurableQueue":true,"deleteNonDurableQueue":true,"manage":true,"browse":false,"createAddress":false,"deleteAddress":false}]

Same output after third:

> [{"name":"test_user","send":true,"consume":true,"createDurableQueue":true,"deleteDurableQueue":true,"createNonDurableQueue":true,"deleteNonDurableQueue":true,"manage":true,"browse":false,"createAddress":false,"deleteAddress":false},{"name":"another_user","send":true,"consume":true,"createDurableQueue":true,"deleteDurableQueue":true,"createNonDurableQueue":true,"deleteNonDurableQueue":true,"manage":true,"browse":false,"createAddress":false,"deleteAddress":false}]

So my question is about last operation. I gave permissions to `last_user` for `ADR.TEST.#`, but there is not any permissions for `ADR.TEST.IN`

Comment: Can you outline the exact steps necessary to reproduce the behavior you're observing? It's not quite clear what management operations you're executing at each step and what parameters you're passing to those management operations.

Comment: @JustinBertram I added some code  samples. Hope now its clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis select only the security settings with most specific match to get the roles for an address.

In your case the security settings with most specific match are:

```
activeMQServerControl.addSecuritySettings("ADR.TEST.IN", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user", "another_user,test_user");
```

To add `last_user` role you should update the security settings with the match `ADR.TEST.IN`, i.e.:

```
activeMQServerControl.addSecuritySettings("ADR.TEST.IN", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user", "another_user,test_user,last_user");
```